# How to link objects in different directories without makefiles?

Tags: c, object-files

I have 3 directories, `src`, `lib`, and `include`. In `include` I have header file `header3.h`. Its code is as follows:

```
//header3.h
extern void change(int *a);
```

In `lib` I have file `change4.c`, which contains:

```
//change4.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header3.h"

void change(int *a){
    int y=100;
    *a=y;
}
```

In `src` I have file `manipulate5.c`, which contains:

```
//manipulate5.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header3.h"

int main(void){
     int x=10;
     printf("x is %d\n", x );
     change(&x);
    printf("x is now %d\n", x );
}
```

I have created object files `manipulate5.o` and `change4.o` for files `manipulate5.c` and `change4.c` respectively. How do I link the two when `manipulate5.o` is in `src` and `change4.o` is in `lib`?

I should further clarify; I am supposed to be able to run the executable when in the `src` directory. Thus, I am not allowed to do the compiling in the root directory.

Comment: Manually. What else?

Comment: You need to fix `change()` — assigning an integer to a pointer is wrong on several grounds.  Use `*a = y;` (and spaces are cheap — use them consistently).

Comment: Assuming current directory is the one holding `src` and `lib`, then `cc -o program src/manipulate5.o lib/change4.o` — where `cc` is the name of your C compiler, of course.  If you've not created the object files, use the names ending `.c`; it won't be much slower on the code shown.

Comment: Can you please tell me what "Manually" entails? And changing change is not the problem; the computer is telling me that change4.o simply does not exist.

Comment: Jonathon Leffler: Thanks for your answer. It works well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use the linker. I am assuming you are on linux. [ld](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) is what you want to use. Something like

```
ld -o executableName lib/change4.o src/manipulate5.o
```

This is assuming you are at the top level of your project. You will also have to change both inclusions of the header to

```
#include "../include/header3.h"
```

Comment: More rules; I am not allowed to use relative pathings in my include statements.

Comment: Then there is no way to do what you want. How does either of those files know where to find the header? You could just put everything into the same directory then.

Comment: I have been doing -I ../include in my compile statements, and it seems work. `include` contains my header.

Comment: So you are using gcc to compile? Then you don't need to use ld. gcc links for you after it compiles. All you need to do is gcc all the o files together. `gcc lib/change4.o src/manipulate5.o`